# Why is the max number of consumers set to 16?

Tags: frame-system

By default, the Substrate node is configured with a maximum number of "consumers" of the address equal to 16.
This means, for example, that a maximum of 16 different tokens (generated by the `assets` pallet) can be stored on one account.

Seems like a pretty strict restriction. What is the core reason to set the limit to 16? Can we safely increase this limit to 1024?

[pallet system](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0d64ba4268106fffe430d41b541c1aeedd4f8da5/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L357)

[runtime config](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0d64ba4268106fffe430d41b541c1aeedd4f8da5/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L227)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the kitchensink runtime are maximum values or anything similar. You could call these numbers reasonable default values or most of the times configurations to make it work. These values are not audited. This entire runtime is just to for testing. You can set these values in your own runtime as you like and then do proper benchmarking and auditing. The entire reason that these values are configurable is to give the user the possibility to set values as they like. However, this also requires that the developer knows on what certain values are doing.